# How do you find the radius of an arc given arc length and height?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image: Valid XHTML].

Please excuse the poor drawing, but how would you go about solving this problem?

Known:

- Arc length
- Height (I'm not sure what the proper term for this parameter is.)

Unknown:

- Sagitta
- Chord length
- Radius

Thank you!

Comment: I see no picture.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that, I needed to revisit the markdown page.

Comment: All the equations are in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) Your $L$ is their $c$, your $s$ is their $h$

Comment: Right, but I don't have either L(c) or s(h). All of the equations in Wikipedia depend on these parameters. The height that I have listed isn't on Wikipedia as a valid parameter.

Comment: Nevermind, I realized this is impossible. I can't find these values without knowing the angle of the circle that this arc encompasses.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible values of $L$, neither of which has a 'nice' expression.

If $R$ is the radius and $\theta$ the angle subtended by the arc, we have
$R \theta = 100$, $L = 2 R \sin {\theta \over 2}$ and
$L \sin {\theta \over 2} = 20$.

Eliminating $R$ gives $L = {200 \over \theta} \sin {\theta \over 2}$, so we can
see that $\theta$ must satisfy
$\theta = 10 \sin^2 {\theta \over 2}$.

A plot of $\theta \mapsto 10 \sin^2 {\theta \over 2}-\theta$ shows two solutions to this equation in $(0,2 \pi)$:
[image]

This gives $\theta_1 \approx 0.406$, $\theta_2 \approx 4.760$.
The corresponding values of $L,R$ are straightforward to compute.
(The drawings look like an ice cream cone and a Pacman.)